# Pack Ubuntu HTML5 click application for desktop

Tags: software-center, application-development, ubuntu-touch, webapps, html5

I would like to pack an Ubuntu HTML5 click application for the Ubuntu Software Center. The application is a game that uses Apache Cordova. It is already published in the click store, I would like to make it available in the Ubuntu Software Center, too. Ideally, it would be executed on the desktop as an ubuntu-html5-webapp application.

Thanks